# Using Typescript generic as key in interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extend `ParsedUrlQuery` allowing for any key to be passed in. Right now I'm creating individual interfaces for a multitude of different parameters, like this:

```
export interface IdParams extends ParsedUrlQuery {
  id: string;
}

export interface SlugParams extends ParsedUrlQuery {
  slug: string;
}
```

What I want to do is creating something reusable that would allow me to do something similar to this:

```
export interface GenericParams<key, value> extends ParsedUrlQuery {
  [key]: value;
}
```

So I could use it anywhere like:

```
GenericParams<"slug", string>
```

or

```
GenericParams<"id", string[]>
```

depending on the needs of the page. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [a mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) here, which can't be an `interface`. But it should work fine as a `type`. The magic here is constraining the key to `string`,  and using `[key in K]` to define the key type.

```
export type GenericParams<K extends string, V> = ParsedUrlQuery & {
  [key in K]: V;
}

type TestA = GenericParams<"slug", string> // { slug: string }
type TestB = GenericParams<"id", string[]> // { id: string[] }
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApygZwgEwKpQA2AigK7QCeyA3gL4CwAUExAB4AOA9lGMqJLEQoAkjnRQ4AW0zI2kEDhnjs+ImUo0myPjgBcyTGCigA5gG4mDZozZcefcNHhJkAZUKkT4qTLkQFShgqBCTkUFTUWgYeJvqGxiDmlkwsHNy8YBTsKADi-tDACN7SADwA0rKs8ooGRqYANMgAagB8yAC8aEG4IerhyABkmozaANoA1hBUoMhlALr6TRaMVkyZ2cgAKhCGAIIdyHkgBUUYPiUARJgxF43xpm0A9I800Z5xdYnIVuso24YAIQORxOxUwl2AOFutQSJlGcyeL2oOg+sPh3yYQA)